# Error with Kaminari pagination in Rails 3

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, pagination, kaminari

I'm trying to implement pagination in my Rails 3 app with Kaminari but I'm getting the following error:

```
undefined method `page' for #<Array:0x007fe43f4b0e80>
```

This is what I have in my controller:

```
@stories = Story.find_all_by_keynote_id(@keynote, :order => 'created_at DESC').page(params[:page])
```

And this is what I put in my view:

```
<%= paginate @stories %>
```

I think there's a problem with the "find_all_by_keynote_id" but I'm not sure how to fix it.

Thank you!

Comment: did you remember to restart your server?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Yes, but how to query the same without an array? That's what I need.

```
@stories = Story.where(:keynote_id => @keynote).order('created_at DESC').page(params[:page])
```

or

```
Keynote.has_many :stories

@stories = @keynote.stories.order('created_at DESC').page(params[:page])
```

Answer (score 5):

Kaminari can also paginate arrays (which is what you have)

```
array = Story.find_all_by_keynote_id(@keynote, :order => 'created_at DESC')
@stories = Kaminari.paginate_array(array).page(params[:page])
```

Comment: Thanks! I didn't know that. I used another approach but with the same result. I put this in my controller `@stories = Story.where("keynote_id = ?", params[:keynote_id]).order("created_at DESC").page(params[:page])`

Comment: I get an undefined method "paginate_array" for Kaminari:module how to solve this?

Answer (score 2):

You are feeding the page method an array when it is expecting an Active Record Relation. If you aren't familiar with that term then you should have a look at the [active record query guide](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_querying.html).

According to the Kaminari docs this is how you are supposed to use it:

```
@stories = Story.order(:created_at).page(params[:page])
```

Comment: Yes, but how to query the same without an array? That's what I need.